# Как на python tkinter вывести консоль в виджет sckrolledtext

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cmd

Представим что у меня есть виджет ScrolledText, и рабочая программа, которая выводит данные в консоль, и мне их нужно поймать и добавить в виджет

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()

output = ScrolledText(root)
output.pack()

# Волшебная функция которая получает данные из консоли
```

Если это поможет, то я захотел сделать программу типа auto-py-to-exe (ведь там это как то организовано), но остановился на этом моменте

Answer (score 0):

Результат выполнения команды можно узнать с помощью функции check_output из модуля subprocess:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from subprocess import check_output

root = Tk()
output = ScrolledText(root)
output.pack()

out = ''
try: 
    out = check_output('КОМАНДА', shell=True)
except:
    out = 'Ошибка выполнения команды.'
output.insert(1.0, out)

root.mainloop()
```